# Error in reading an array assigned to Data- in Jquery. I am using .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following HTML generated on the server through an AJAX call. Of course there is a lot more than this but the following line is relevant:

```
 <div id="mydiv" DATA-mylist='[ [0,0],  [1,0],  [4,1],  [6,1],  [7,1], ]'>...</div>
```

I need to extract the **array** assigned to DATA-mylist and assign it to a property as in:

```
 $('#somediv').mywidget({
     prop1 : 45, //For example
     arr_prop : $('#mydiv').data('mylist') 
 });
```

Here arr_prop expects an array. It is not getting one. I get the following error:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '12' in [ [0,0], ..
```

I tried a few things to get it to work, other than using the .attr() method instead of .data() which I think is not the right approach anyway. I am possibly missing something very basic somewhere. Please help!

Comment: check the `mywidget` the `data` part works fine http://jsfiddle.net/28Kzh/

Comment: You are probably right. Let me look further. Upvoted your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @melc Actually no, it returns a string http://jsfiddle.net/28Kzh/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `,` in your array is the culprit:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-mylist="[ [0,0], [1,0], [4,1], [6,1], [7,1],]">...</div>
                                                           -----^
```

By adding the extra `,` `.data()` method returns a string instead of an array as it fails to parse the string, you can see the difference [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Sss/).

Comment: Does not take care of my problem. I changed the server side code to reflect your suggestion and generate without that extra comma. Same error persists. It worked earlier with the same string but I was generating the entire JS on the server side and generating using .attr() to get the array string. Will look further. Your answer was helpful. Upvoting it. If that was also a problem, will accept it too later.

Comment: @Samir In which line do you get that error, can you post the related code? It seems there is also another problem.

Comment: The array I am referring to is the sortList property of tablesorter. See http://tablesorter.com/docs/. I want to assign data-mylist value to that property. I am getting error on that line where sortList is assigned the value. If I write a static HTML with the same string/array, its fine. That is what is bugging me.

Comment: @Samir Unfortunately I haven't used `tablesorter` plugin so far, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502101/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-324-in) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878945/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-error-on-init-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined).

Comment: That should do it. Thanks.

Comment: There must be a way to do without JSON too. I will post a comment if I get it to work because I did have it working without JSON  when I was generating the entire JS on the server side. Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: Got it! I simply assigned the Data-value to a variable and then assigned the variable to the tablesorter sortList. All's fine. Almost! Now i need to find out why.